# Configuring restrictExtent

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-12.04, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm using a fresh installation of Ubuntu's Mapnik and this is my map configuration:

```
        map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({geodesic: true})],
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(13.543,45.932,13.553,45.939),
            maxResolution: 156543.0339,
            numZoomLevels: 19,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
            displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        } );
```

This configuration works fine (even if I'm not sure it is using maxExtent). If I add `restrictedExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds(13.543,45.932,13.553,45.939)`, the map acts as Bounds constructor parameters are `(0,0,0,0)`.
Without this option, my map correctly centers at my "LatLon" definition.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to transform your bounds from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 (the same as EPSG:900913) projection:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map ("map", {
    // ...
    restrictedExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(13.543, 45.932, 13.553, 45.939).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
    )
    // ...
};
```

BTW, personally I have all these projection objects created earlier, so in remaining code all my transforms look like

```
// Init section
var EPSG4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
var EPSG3857 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857");

// ...
something.transform(EPSG4326, EPSG3857);
```